# Factorial using recursion

Tags: java

```
Class A {

 Int fact(int n)
{
If (n==1)
   Return 1;
Else 
   Return fact(n-1)*n;
}

}
Class B {

Public static void main(String a[])
{
    A f=new A();
    System.out.println("fact of 5 is"+f.fact(5));
}

}
```

Comment: In this program we are using fact(n-1)*n logic instead of this why don't we use fact(n) both will give same result right??

Comment: What is the issue ??? you should mention the issue that you are facing. Edit your question

Comment: Please edit your question to properly format the code, and don't post the question as a comment.

Comment: so what is the problem that you are facing

Comment: In that there are no errors my question is fact(5)=5*4*3*2*1=120 why we are not using return fact(n) instead of fact(n-1)*n

Comment: Because it would go into an endless loop. The flow of this method is only controlled by the parameter given so if you call it recursively with the same parameter, the method won't behave any differently. And how would you expect the method to actually multiply the parameter with all the smaller positive integers?

Answer (score 1):

Recursion approach aims to solve problems by finding a pattern while solving a problem!
We know for finding a factorial of a number n we would get it easily by multiplying the number with factorial of n-1 . Thus

```
6!= 6 * 5!
```

OR,

```
Fact(n)= n * Fact(n-1)
```

Now This would cause

```
Fact(6)= 6 * Fact(5);
           = 6 * (5 * Fact(4));
```

Every step decrements n and we stop this when we encounter 1 or 0 in whose case we simply return 1

Finally the compiler uses the value of 
Fact(1) to compute Fact(2) which in turn computes Fact(3) retracing all the way back to the number whose factorial is desired

Recursion though often more elegant & suitable is a strain on memory(read about activation records,stacks in Recursion) because everything about the functions called recursively is stored till the function exits. This problem could be eliminated by using tail  Recursion or not employing Recursion at all

Comment: I understood now thanq doode

Answer (score 0):

As per your statement following code will return the same result :

```
Class A{

Int fact(int n)

{ If (n==1)

Return 1;

Else

Return fact(n);

}

} Class B {

Public static void main(String a[])

{

A f=new A();

System.out.println("fact of 5 is"+f.fact(5));

}

}
```

But, suppose you are calling fact(5). In that case control will go to the else block and again it will return and call fact(5) and so on. So there will not be an end of this method call.

Comment: Can u please explain it??

Comment: Okay!what happens if i use fact(n-1)*n can you please explain it??